# Will querying sudoers for checking permissions using "sudo -l -u -U cmd" always work?

Tags: linux, sudo

Scenario:
My shell is running as `user_A`. I want to check if `user_B` has permission to run the command `sample_cmd` as `user_C`.

I am using `sudo -n -l -u user_C -U user_B sample_cmd` to achieve this. None of the users have root permissions.

Will this always work or am I missing cases where this may fail?

Comment: It will fail if user A needs to enter a password.

Answer (score 0):

For one, the man page says, of `-U`:

> The security policy may restrict listing other users' privileges.  The sudoers policy only allows root or a user with the ALL privilege on the current host to use this option.

So it would seem it will fail if `user_A` doesn't have enough privileges.

E.g. I get

```
$ sudo -l -u foo -U root ls
Sorry, user ilkkachu is not allowed to execute '/bin/ls' as root on thishost.
```

The error message is also a bit confusing, since it refers to me not being allowed to run the command, not to if user `foo` is allowed.

Comment: Thanks, @ilkkachu. I am observing the same error for a new user that is created. But, for another user (not having root permission), I am not getting this error. I am checking as to why that is the case.